# How do I troubleshoot 'Theme key "" not found'?

Tags: debugging

How do I troubleshoot the error `Theme key "" not found`?

I found dozens of search results regarding specific keys, but nothing useful for debugging an empty key ("").

Here is the full entry from syslog:

```
Sep 12 09:45:47 core drupal: http://www.example.com|1347457547|theme|192.168.1.10|http://www.example.com/|http://www.example.com/admin/config/development/logging|1||Theme key "" not found.
```

What exactly triggers this error and how should I go about debugging it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning message comes from `theme()` function in `includes/theme.inc`. For temporary debug you could just add `ddebug_backtrace()` there (if you're using [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module) to see where the call comes from (and see what are the params). If not using Devel, just check output of `debug_backrace()`. And then it all depends what you are going to find out...